# Difference between running via Firefox versus Selenium WebDriver (GeckoDriver)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I'm trying to scrape my own banking information by automating the process using Selenium in Ruby.

I'm running into a bizarre situation where performing the exact same sequence in the browser (whether just the normal browser or private/incognito) works fine, but when I try to log in under a Selenium-controlled browser I get back a strange 500 error from the server.

I've noticed the browser console logs also look different in terms of certain logging messages related to cookies, JS errors, libraries being loaded, etc.

I have found an answer on SO mentioning one possible difference in *Chrome* being a specific "cdc" string that might be detectable, but is there some kind of corresponding difference in Firefox/Geckodriver that could be used to detect the fact that I'm trying to automate the browser?

I'm not really sure where to look, because my understand was that running via Selenium should basically have identical behaviour to running via the browser itself.

Would love some guidance on what mechanisms may be in play to explain the difference in behaviour!

Comment: It should be same, try different browser such as chrome, FF, edge, safari etc for automation

Comment: @cruisepandey There are definitely some differences. I've noticed that at the very least a property called `navigator.webdriver` is set to `true`. That seems to actually be a part of the WebDriver specification and is not removable in any kind of straightforward way, so it looks like that would be a trivial check that could be performed in JS to check for the presence of a webdriver.